# What exactly is "nostrification" of a university diploma?

Tags: degree, international

I have been reading a bit about nostrification of a university diploma, but I don't quite understand what it means. I do understand that nostrification is basically validation of your diploma in a foreign country. But, does it **only** mean that your diploma is recognized in this foreign country (so you can actually take a job there, or you can continue to a higher education there) or it actually means that you can go to a university at this foreign country and require the same degree diploma from that university?

For example, if you have a civil engineering degree from a university in country A, and you do nostrification in country B, does it also mean that you can go to a university that offers a civil engineering programme in country B, and just require a degree diploma from that university cause you already had one from country A?

Comment: Why would you expect the latter? You could not do that with a diploma from another university in the same country either.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You can actually, if the curriculum is the same in both universities, just transfer the credits and you are more or less done (in rare instances).

Comment: No, that is not even close to true. If it were, there would be a lot more people with diplomas from places like Harvard and MIT.

Comment: In order to transfer credits, you first need to get accepted by that university, which is a lot harder than getting your foreign degree recognized.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere. Once you have a degree, you usually don't enroll for the same degree in another university.

Comment: @terett You keep forgetting that in Europe, while you can transfer your ETCS credits to another university, this new university: (1) has different rules set up for many things, (2) can lower the number of ETCS credits it acknowledges, (3) won't acknowledge your thesis (final project) defense, and defending the same thesis twice could be considered a very serious self-plagiarism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nostrification is verification that Degree X you received in Country A has the same value as Degree Y received in Country B. You do not receive a new diploma for Degree Y in Country B.

Well, actually a university in Country B may decide to give you Degree Y based on your work in Country A, but it's certainly not standard, and usually bond to university-level agreement and cooperated studies, but even then it's often not the degree that's nostrificated, but rather the thesis, its reports etc. and the defense that's considered.

The most common reason for diploma nostrification is (1) job requirements in Country B, often in governmental jobs such as offices, schools etc.; or (2) continuation of study, for instance nostrification of Masters for the admission to PhD studies in Country B. In neither case, it is necessary to have Degree Y in Country B.